# Pass comma separated key string and get value of array according to key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to get value from array and pass only comma separated key string and get same output without. Is it possible without using foreach statement. Please suggest me.

```
<?php
$str = "1,2,3";
$array = array("1"=>"apple", "2"=>"banana", "3"=>"orange");

$keyarray = explode(",",$str);
$valArr = array();
foreach($keyarray as $key){
   $valArr[] = $array[$key];
}
echo $valStr = implode(",", $valArr);    
?>
```

Output : `apple,banana,orange`

Comment: What is the result getting by your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_intersect_key

```
$str = "1,2,3";
$array = array("1"=>"apple", "2"=>"banana", "3"=>"orange");

$keyarray = explode(",",$str);
echo implode(",", array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keyarray)));
```

https://3v4l.org/gmcON

---

One liner:

```
echo implode(",", array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(explode(",",$str))));
```

A mess to read but a comment above can explain what it does.
It means you don't need the $keyarray

Comment: Looks like the most clever answer but I tested and get `apple,banana` as output (missing `orange`)

Comment: @AymDev True I had to eat some of my comment, one array_flip is needed. Answer edited

Comment: Now it makes sense ! +1

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestion** : Use separate row for each value, to better operation. Although you have created right code to get from `Comma sparate key` to `Value from array`, but If you need it without any loop, PHP has some inbuilt functions like `array_insersect` , `array_flip` to same output

```
$str = "1,2";
$arr1 = ["1"=>"test1","2"=>"test2","3"=>"test3"];
$arr2  = explode(",",$str);
echo implode(", ",array_flip(array_intersect(array_flip($arr1),$arr2)));
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/1050567)

Comment: Looks better than my answer, nice one !

Comment: You don't need array_flip with array_intersect_key

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `array_filter`:

```
$str = "1,2,3";
$array = array("1"=>"apple", "2"=>"banana", "3"=>"orange");

$keyarray = explode(",",$str);

$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v,$k) use($keyarray){
    return in_array($k, $keyarray);
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

print_r($filtered);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [1] => apple
    [2] => banana
    [3] => orange
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
echo $valStr = implode(",", array_map(function ($i) use ($array) { return $array[$i]; }, explode(",", $str)));
```

Read it from bottom to top:

```
echo $valStr = implode(                 // 3. glue values
    ",",
    array_map(                          // 2. replace integers by fruits
        function ($i) use ($array) {
            return $array[$i];
        },
        explode(",", $str)              // 1. Split values
    )
);
```